# Json Reference field in Json Variant return Error when the Reference Field Is empty

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api, json

I am using SXA Json Content to create API. In the JSON Variant, I used Reference Field to display Drop Link Field in the data.

But when the DropLink field is empty, the API returns error. So I need to know where the code related to render the Reference Items in JSON Variant to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON Variants just like normal Rendering Variants are using `RenderVariantField` pipeline to define processors. Each processor is responsible for rendering the different type of a variant item.

The reference is rendered using `RenderJsonReference.cs`. I would need to double-check, but it seems to me that a potential null check is missing in the code. But have fun and check it on your side. I'm looking forward to your investigation!